# Swift2 handle data from POST

Tags: json, post, swift2

Im sending a Post message to my database with swift. But how do i handle the data from that response? My variable responseString looks like this now. I want to get each parameter and work with them.

> Optional([{"id":"9","name":"hallow","strasse":"street","tel_nr":"123456789","kommentar":"comment"}])

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/getByName.php")!)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "name=hallow"

    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Don't make the JSON data into a string, you won't be able to do anything with it. Instead, use NSJSONSerialization to make the JSON data into objects (an array of dictionaries in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Your php is returning an array containing a dictionary, so you'd have to access it like 
`if let responsedict = response.first {
     print(responsedict["id"])
}// prints 9`

(if you know there's going to be no other elements returned first is ok...or change how your data is sent back).

You could take it one step further and parse the response in to a model e.g.

```
let person = Person(id: response.first?["id"], name: response.first?["name"], etc)
print("id \(person.id)") 
//id 9
```

Comment: @Korken55 I told you the solution in my comment under your question. Maybe you missed it.